# How to set the Anchorable View Floating/Hiding Manually for WPF Dirkster AvalonDock(v4.60.1) with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, avalondock

I'm using Dirkster AvalonDock(v4.60.1) with MVVM pattern in my WPF project.
I would like to change the *AnchorableView* state into float or hide through my View Model but unfortunately there are not much examples for me to refer.

The way I did was to control the view state in a class called *LayoutInitializer*, which handling the *LayoutUpdateStrategy* for my AvalonDock.

Here is my XAML code for Avalon Dock:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
    <helper:LayoutInitializer/>
</avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
```

With the above code, the XAML will create the *LayoutInitializer* class on its own, and through this class it is able to control the **AvalonDock Elements (eg. LayoutRoot, LayoutAnchorable, Container, etc.)**

Below is the code of my *LayoutInitializer* class to set the *AnchorableView* state (float or hide):

```
public void AfterInsertAnchorable(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutAnchorable anchorableShown)
    {
        anchorableShown.FloatingHeight = 300;
        anchorableShown.FloatingWidth = 400;
        anchorableShown.FloatingTop = 150;
        anchorableShown.FloatingLeft = 1000;
        anchorableShown.CanDockAsTabbedDocument = false;
        anchorableShown.CanMove = false;
        anchorableShown.CanAutoHide = true;
        anchorableShown.Float();
        //anchorableShown.Hide();
    }
```

It works fine on its own, however in some cases I will need to change the *AnchorableView* state to Float/Hide manually through my **ViewModel**.

I've tried to create another new instance of *LayoutInitializer* class from my *ViewModel*, but this new created *LayoutInitializer* class can not access the **AvalonDock Elements**, and it will also result in duplicate class for *LayoutInitializer*.

> So, How should I set the *AnchorableView* state from my **ViewModel** manually?

Q2.

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
    <helper:LayoutInitializer/>
</avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
```

I can think of another way to try, which is bind a property for *LayoutInitializer* to the XAML code.

Instead of calling

> **helper:LayoutInitializer/**

I may **bind a property of *LayoutInitializer* in my ViewModel with the XAML code**, by this method the **ViewModel** can share the same object of *LayoutInitializer* class and my **ViewModel** can also change the *AnchorableView* state (float/hide)!

> But How can I bind the *LayoutInitializer* from my ViewModel to the XAML code (avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy)?

#One quick question: Does anyone still using AvalonDock for WPF, or are there other Nuget library for docking the view?

It is quite a complicated issue, sorry if my question confuse you.
But I really need some help from you guys! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70859006/how-to-create-avalondock-layoutinitializer-in-viewmodel-and-bind-it-to-the-xaml/70859856#70859856) Here is the way to bind the *LayoutInitializer* in the **ViewModel** with the **View**. With this method, you are able to access the **AvalonDock Elements**, you can freely change the state of the *layout document* or *layout anchorable* or even access to the *layout root* in the *LayoutInitializer* class.